# How to find the source code for a Gradle task visible in IntelliJ Gradle projects window?

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle

I have got a large Java/IntelliJ/Gradle project from the repository. It has many tasks in `Gradle projects window`, but I cannot find definitions for some of them. Even by Total Commander, in the whole workspace. There are dependencies on some of them, but I can't see the code of the task.

Comment: A plugin can add tasks, I'm guessing you are `apply`ing plugins which are adding the tasks to the model

Comment: Sorry, I hadn't understood you at first. You mean, some tasks are on the external scripts out of the workspace or somewhere on the net? Yes, that could be the answer.

Comment: When you say `apply plugin: 'xxx'` that plugin can add tasks to the gradle model. For example see [here](https://docs.gradle.org/3.3/userguide/java_plugin.html#sec:java_tasks) for the tasks added by the 'java' plugin

Comment: Could you put your info as an answer here?

Answer (score 4):

The task could have been defined explicitly in the build.gradle file or can come from a plugin (as others have mentioned)

To get more information about the task, use command-line

```
./gradlew help --task <task>
```

or

```
gradle help --task <task>
```

Comment: According to http://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2015/09/gradle-goodness-getting-more-help-for.html, the 'help' task does not output the placement of the source of the 'task' parameter. Or, at least, I don't see it. If you have other experience, please, put an example output into your answer and ping me with a comment. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Somewhat outdated, but since I actually had the same question:

Clone spring-framework from Github, examine task "java21Test".

```
gradle help --task java21Test
```

leads to

```
:spring-core:java21Test
```

In the `spring-core` directory you find `spring-core.gradle`, which takes you to

```
plugins {
    id 'me.champeau.mrjar'
}
```

And deep in the source (`MultiReleaseExtension.java`) you find

```
TaskProvider<Test> testTask = tasks.register("java" + version + "Test", ...
```